Evaluate $\sum_{k=0}^{L-1} (-1)^k \frac{1 + w^2 \tan^2\left(\frac{k \pi}{L}\right)}{1 + w \tan\left(\frac{k \pi}{L}\right)}$
Is there a way to evaluate one of the sums:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{L-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{1 + w \tan\left(\frac{k \pi}{L}\right)},$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{L-1} \frac{1}{1 + w \tan\left(\frac{k \pi}{L}\right)},$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{L-1} \frac{1 + w^2 \tan^2\left(\frac{k \pi}{L}\right)}{1 + w \tan\left(\frac{k \pi}{L}\right)}?$$
in a closed form?
They appear in a form of Grover's algorithm, when maintaining the fixed-point. (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3305)
Edit: I realized that I actually need only this summation:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{L-1} (-1)^k \frac{1 + w^2 \tan^2\left(\frac{k \pi}{L}\right)}{1 + w \tan\left(\frac{k \pi}{L}\right)},$$
where $L$ is odd.
I tried to rewrite the tangens as exponentials:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{L-1} (-1)^k\frac{w^2 (z^2 - 1)^2 - (z^2 + 1)^2}{(z^2 + 1) \left(i w (z^2 - 1) - z^2 - 1\right)},z=e^{i \frac{k \pi}{L}}$$
Unfortunately, I do not know how to proceed from this stage on. Any insights on methods to approach these sums, or ideas on closed forms for particular cases, would be greatly appreciated!

Unsure if useful, but one might consider to use $re^{\iota \theta} = r \cos \theta ( 1 + \iota \tan \theta)$

Using complex integration, we can get closed forms for your cases B and C. For the case A there is a closed form at even L; in the case of odd L the sum can be presented as an integral. I would recommend you to add some information regarding your task (why the problem is important, your efforts and approaches to solve it); otherwise, the problem can be closed.

Thank you for your answers. I added the reason of why the problem is important. Also, I am currently trying to understand how complex integration can solve the problem. Useful hints would be appreciated.

The first two terms (below) bring the main contribution at $L\gg1$; the last two $\sim \frac\omega {\pi L}$. The approximation works perfectly already at $L=11$. Numeric check with WA confirms the result: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E11%28%28-1%29%5Ek%281%2B0.09%5Ctan%5E2%28%5Cpi++k%2F11%29%29%2F%281%2B0.3%5Ctan%28%5Cpi+k%2F11%29%29%29 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-6.6%2F%281%2B0.09%29%2F%5Csin%2811%5Carctan%2810%2F3%29%29%2B3.3%2F%5Csin%2811%5Cpi%2F2%29%2B0.3%5Cpi%2F22
I will post the sulution a bit later: it is late at night :)

Corrected a typo.
For odd $L$ and $\frac1\omega\neq\tan\frac{\pi k}L,, k=0, \pm1, \pm2,..\pm ,L,,$(note that the summation below is up to $L$)
$$\sum_{k=0}^L (-1)^k \frac{1 + w^2 \tan^2\left(\frac{k \pi}{L}\right)}{1 + w \tan\left(\frac{k \pi}{L}\right)}=-\frac{2\omega L}{1+\omega^2}\frac1{\sin(L\arctan\frac1\omega)}+\frac{\omega L}{\sin\frac{\pi L}2}$$
$$+\frac\omega\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1-\omega^2\tanh^2\frac xL}{1+\omega^2\tanh^2\frac xL},\frac{\tanh\frac xL}{\sinh x}dx$$

Looking forward!

Let's start from the simpliest case of
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^L\frac1{1+\omega\tan\frac{\pi k}L}$$
We consider a rectangular contour $C$ in the complex plane: $-iR\to-iR+L\to iR+L\to iR\to -iR$. We also add arches around $z=0$ and $z=L$, so that these points stay inside the contour.
In a standart way, denoting $z_0=L-\frac L\pi\arctan\frac1\omega$
$$I=\frac1\omega\oint_C\frac{\pi\cot\pi z}{\frac1\omega+\tan\frac{\pi z}L}dz=\frac{2\pi i}\omega\left(\sum\underset{z=0,1,...L}{\operatorname{Res}}+\underset{z=z_0}{\operatorname{Res}}\right)\frac{\pi\cot\pi z}{\frac1\omega+\tan\frac{\pi z}L}$$
$$=2\pi i\left(S+\frac{L\omega}{\pi(1+\omega^2)}\cot\pi z_0\right)$$
On the othe hand, integrating explicitly, we see that the integrals along the paths $-iR+L\to iR+L$ and $iR\to -iR$ cancel each other (due to the symmetry of the integrand and integration in the opposite directions). Also,
$\cot\pi(iR+x)\to-i$ at $R\to\infty$. We also have to integrate along small half-circles around $z=0$ and $z=L$ (what gives us half-residues).
Taking all together,
$$I=2\pi i\left(S-\frac{L\omega}{\pi(1+\omega^2)}\cot\pi z_0\right)=2\pi i+\frac{\pi i}\omega\int_0^L\left(\frac1{\frac1\omega-i}+\frac1{\frac1\omega+i}\right)dz$$
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^L\frac1{1+\omega\tan\frac{\pi k}L}=1+\frac L{1+\omega^2}+\frac{L\omega}{1+\omega^1}\cot(L\arctan\frac1\omega)$$
$$\boxed{\,\,\sum_{k=0}^{L-1}\frac1{1+\omega\tan\frac{\pi k}L}=\frac L{1+\omega^2}+\frac{L\omega}{1+\omega^2}\cot(L\arctan\frac1\omega)\,\,}\tag{1}$$
Just to note that we suppose that $\frac1\omega\neq\tan\frac{\pi k}L,\,k=0,\,1,\,2...,\, \,L\,$ - otherwise we get the infinite term in our sum.

Numeric check: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7B19%7D+1%2F%281%2B0.6%5Ctan%28%5Cpi+k%2F20%29%29 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=20%2F1.36%2B%2820%5Ccdot0.6%29%2F1.36%5Ccot%2820%5Carctan%2810%2F6%29%29

In the similar way we evaluate
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^L\frac{(-1)^k}{1+\omega\tan\frac{\pi k}L},\,\,L-\,\text{even}$$
The only difference is that we integrate $\frac1{\frac1\omega+\tan\frac{\pi z}L}\,\frac\pi{\sin\pi z}$, and the integrals along the paths $-iR+L\to iR+L$ and $iR\to -iR\,$ tend to zero (exponentially) at $R\to\infty$
$$\boxed{\,\,\sum_{k=0}^{L-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{1+\omega\tan\frac{\pi k}L}=\frac{L\omega}{1+\omega^2}\,\frac1{\sin(L\arctan\frac1\omega)},\,\, L\,\,\text{is even}\,\,}\tag{2}$$

Numeric check: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E9%28-1%29%5Ek%2F%281%2B0.3%5Ctan%28%5Cpi+k%2F10%29%29 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=3%2F%281%2B0.09%29%2F%28%5Csin%2810%5Carctan%2810%2F3%29%29%29

In the case of odd $L$ we cannot get such a simple form: the integrals along the paths $\,-iR+L\to iR+L$ and $iR\to -iR\,$ do not cancel each other. The sum of half residues at the points $z=0,L$ is zero in this case.
The evaluation gives
$$\boxed{\,\,\sum_{k=0}^L\frac{(-1)^k}{1+\omega\tan\frac{\pi k}L}=-\frac{L\omega}{1+\omega^2}\,\frac1{\sin(L\arctan\frac1\omega)}+\frac\omega\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\tanh\frac x L}{1+\omega^2\tanh^2\frac x L}\frac{dx}{\sinh x},\,\, L\,\,\text{is odd}\,\,}\tag{3}$$

Numeric check: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7B11%7D%28-1%29%5Ek%2F%281%2B0.3%5Ctan%28%5Cpi+k%2F11%29%29 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-3.3%2F1.09%2F%5Csin%2811%5Carctan%2810%2F3%29%29%2B0.3%5Cpi%2F22

For your last sum, making straightforward transformations (just note that we are summing up to $L$, not $L-1$)
$$\sum_{k=0}^L (-1)^k \frac{1 + w^2 \tan^2\left(\frac{k \pi}{L}\right)}{1 + w \tan\left(\frac{k \pi}{L}\right)}=\sum_{k=0}^L(-1)^k\left(-1+\omega\tan\frac{\pi k}L+\frac2{1+\omega\tan\frac{\pi k}L}\right)$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^L(-1)^k\left(\omega\tan\frac{\pi k}L+\frac2{1+\omega\tan\frac{\pi k}L}\right),\,\,\text{if} \,\,L\,\,\text{is odd}$$
The similar and straightforward evaluation gives
$$\sum_{k=0}^L (-1)^k \frac{1 + w^2 \tan^2\left(\frac{k \pi}{L}\right)}{1 + w \tan\left(\frac{k \pi}{L}\right)}=-\,\frac{2\omega L}{1+\omega^2}\frac1{\sin(L\arctan\frac1\omega)}+\frac{\omega L}{\sin\frac{\pi L}2}$$
$$+\frac\omega\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1-\omega^2\tanh^2\frac xL}{1+\omega^2\tanh^2\frac xL}\,\frac{\tanh\frac xL}{\sinh x}dx,\,\,L\,\,\text{is odd};\,\frac1\omega\neq\tan\frac{\pi k}L, \,k=0,1,...L\tag{4}$$
This is the most closed form - if we want to express the sum by means of integral. The formula allows to evaluate as many asymptotic terms as we want (at $L\gg1$) via the decomposition of the integrand in the powers of $\frac xL$
$$\frac\omega\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1-\omega^2\tanh^2\frac xL}{1+\omega^2\tanh^2\frac xL}\,\frac{\tanh\frac xL}{\sinh x}dx=\frac\omega{\pi L}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac x{\sinh x}dx+O\Big(\frac1{L^3}\Big)=\frac{\omega\pi}{2L}+O\Big(\frac1{L^3}\Big)$$
what provides a decent level of accuracy even for comparatively small $L\sim 10$

@Gary, thank you! I corrected numeric check in the formula (3) (really, lost 1/2 in the last term in WA evaluation - I added a correct link; now, the numeric agreement is as it should be). Also, corrected typos in the evaluation of the formula (4) (lost $(-1)^k$ before parenthese in two places)

Maybe, I did not catch the point...

Great job! Very helpful!!!!

Thank you for the interesting problem! I'm glad that I can help.

Lets write
$$
u_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{1 + \omega \tan\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)}\quad v_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{1 + \omega \tan\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)} \quad w_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1 + \omega^2 \tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)}{1 + \omega \tan\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)}
$$
Splitting even and odd terms, we have
$$
v_{2n} = 2 u_n - u_{2n}
$$
We also get
$$
w_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{\left(1 + \omega \tan\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)\right)^2 - 2 \left(1 + \omega \tan\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)\right) + 2}{1 + \omega \tan\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)} = 2u_n - n + \omega \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \tan\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)
$$
You can then see that $w_n$ is infinite at even $n$ and is $2u_n - n$ at odd $n$.

This is only a partial answer to compute an equivalent of $u_n$, as $n \to \infty$ :
$$
\pi \frac{u_n}{n} \to \int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2} \frac{\textrm{d}t}{1 + \omega \tan(t)} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(u)\textrm{d}u
$$
where
$$
F(u) = \frac{1}{(1 + \omega u)(1 + u^2)} = \frac{\alpha}{1 + \omega u} + \frac{\beta u + \gamma}{1 + u^2} \quad \left(\alpha = \frac{\omega^2}{1 + \omega^2} \quad \beta = \frac{-\omega}{1 + \omega^2} \quad \gamma = \frac{1}{1 + \omega^2}\right)
$$
So
$$
\pi \frac{u_n}{n} \to \lim_{M \to \infty} \left[ \frac{\alpha}{\omega} \ln(1 + \omega u) \right]_{-M}^{M} - \left[ \frac{\beta}{2} \ln(1 + u^2) \right]_{-M}^{M} + [\gamma \arctan(u)]_{-M}^{M} = \frac{\omega \ln \omega + \pi}{1 + \omega^2}
$$
